# Build dynamic linq select query from existing list

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, iqueryable

So I'm trying to make dynamic reports, that our users can save and later reference.   I decided I wanted to use linq for this, and learn some more about it.   I feel like I have a good chunk of this figured out, but am stumped at the very end.  Here's my code

```
protected void executeReport(CustomerCustomReports report)
{
    string fields = report.fields;
    ReportsDataContext db = new ReportsDataContext();
    string[]filters = fields.Split(';');

        var inventoryList = (from cust in db.Customers
                             join product in db.Products on cust.customerID equals product.customerID
                             join inventory in db.Inventories on product.itemID equals inventory.ItemId
                             join warehouse in db.Warehouses on inventory.WarehouseId equals warehouse.Id
                             where cust.customerID == customer.CustomerId
                             select new
                             {
                                 ItemID = product.itemID,
                                 ItemDescription = product.shortDesc,
                                 CustomsValue = product.unitPrice
                             }).OrderBy(k => k.ItemID);

ParameterExpression sourceItem = Expression.Parameter(inventoryList.ElementType, "x");

        Type resultType = typeof(linqResult);

        var dynamicFields = new List<MemberBinding>();
        foreach (string f in filters)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(f))
            {
                dynamicFields.Add(Expression.Bind(resultType.GetMember(f)[0], Expression.Property(sourceItem, inventoryList.ElementType.GetProperty(f))));
            }
        }
        Expression selector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(resultType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)), dynamicFields), sourceItem);


        var query = inventoryList.Provider.CreateQuery(
                Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable),
                    "Select",
                    new Type[] { inventoryList.ElementType, resultType },
                Expression.Constant(inventoryList), selector));

        var listResult = new List<object>();
        var enumerator = query.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            listResult.Add(enumerator.Current);
        }


        gvResults.DataSource = listResult;
        gvResults.DataBind();

}
```

With a class like this

```
 public class linqResult
 {
  public string ItemID {get; set;}
  public string ItemDescription {get; set;}
  public string CustomsValue {get; set;}
 }
```

My aim is to have the full list and then only display the properties the customer wants.

Comment: Any kind of help of suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering what it is you're looking for, more specifically.    You can take your results and `.ToList()` them, and your linq comes back as a collection (that matches your linqResult object) -- but those new selects end up being temporary anonymous types anyhow, that have what you need.    If you want the full list of properties, don't do the `select new...` bit on the query, just `select`.     like  `select cust;`

Comment: You really shouldn't be using LINQ here at all.  LINQ is fundamentally designed for performing database queries *on data that you know the schema of at compile time*.  Having a static DB/query schema allows it to provide all sorts of additional features over entirely dynamic querying tools.  You inherently have an entirely dynamic schema, so you're not benefiting from any of LINQ's actual features, and being harmed a lot by having to do a whole lot more work to do your query.  Just construct the raw SQL with strings.

Comment: @Servy -- I think they want dynamic reports, not dynamic data.  I guess I read it as "I want all the data from the query, but only spit out what I want in the report -- but keep it all in case I want to review the pulled info at a later date".

Comment: @Jason The query is dynamically determining which columns to pull from the database.  That's dynamically changing the schema of the query.  If the OP has no problem pulling unneeded data they can pull everything and then only show certain columns on the UI side, but then they're wasting a lot of network traffic.

Comment: Ok thank you.   I will rethink this.

Comment: @Jason that is what I wanted.

Comment: @NycoleMoore -- Linq to SQL was built to handle returning back an anonymous type (selecting NEW like you had -- so don't fret over Servy's comments).     We're not talking network traffic or throughput here, we're talking functionality, and you're on the right track.   Check my answer below that I did give you -- it might help get you going.    Linq2SQL results can be put into a list and enumerated, and you can cast it into your linkresult class type, also - or just keep the whole .ToList() collection (JSON serialize, store in DB, read later?) - somewhere.    Things to get you thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<LinqResult> inventoryList = (from cust in db.Customers
                             join product in db.Products on cust.customerID equals product.customerID
                             join inventory in db.Inventories on product.itemID equals inventory.ItemId
                             join warehouse in db.Warehouses on inventory.WarehouseId equals warehouse.Id
                             where cust.customerID == customer.CustomerId
                             select cust).OrderBy(k => k.ItemID).ToList();
```

Does this work?    I punched it out here on the website, but the jist is to just get your list collection right from the query, and Type cast it into your LinqResult as you get it.   You may need to cast it at the ToList -- but play with that, see what it does for you.